# Get data info in HTML field using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have an automatic field calculated with data attributes, but I can't use that field so i want to replicate the functionality using Jquery, I want a button to do that with Jquery function and populate a text field.

Initially I had this:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-1" value="female" id="forminator-field-radio-1-2-608c8cfc0bc56" data-calculation="0">
```

and several like the one before,
and then the auto populated field has:

```
<input type="number" name="calculation-1" value="" id="calculation-1-field" class="test-calculation" data-formula="({radio-1} * (10*{number-2} + 6.25*{number-3}) * {number-2})" data-required="" data-precision="0" data-is-hidden="" disabled="disabled">
```

However, I want the button with JQuery to do something similar but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','#calculatecal',function(){
    $("#caloryid h3").html({radio-1});
});

</script>
```

The script doesn't get that radio-1, how can I query the data? either the data-calculation or how to simulate the data-formula?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hi i dont get the idea but maybe you looking for this!?!

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','#calculatecal',function(){
    $("#caloryid h3").html({radio-1} * (10*{number-2} + 6.25*{number-3});
});

</script>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, however, inside the "data-formula" it understands what is radio 1, but outside it doesn't, that's why I'm wondering if there's any command so that I can use the "radio 1" without adding one additional class to every element and finding it with jquery like $(id)

Comment: are you maybe  looking for   
`$('td[name="radio-1"]')   // Matches exactly 'radio-1'`  
`$('td[name^="radio"]' )  // Matches those that begin with 'radio'`     
`$('td[name$="-1"]' )  // Matches those that end with '-1' `  
`$('td[name*="radio"]' )  // Matches those that contain 'radio'  

here is a [Link for more info](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)